# Replace expression between two punctuation letters in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, str-replace

I have a string like the following,

```
var str = "abcd-12ad3dgs4g56.com"
```

I want like the following from this

```
abcd.com
```

I have to replace only `-*.` expression with `.`.
How do I do this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply try this

```
str.replace( /-\w+/, "" ); //"abcd.com"
```

```js
    var str = "abcd-12ad3dgs4g56.com"
    console.log(str.replace(/-\w+/, ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression with a positive lookahead.

```js
var str = "abcd-12ad3dgs4g56.com";

console.log(str.replace(/-.*(?=\.)/g, ''));
```